# How do I hide this message while typing in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

When I type this annoying line appears and hides what I'm writing
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzBBS.png)

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered similar problem and this helped me. Try to add in **config.lua**:

```
vim.opt.title = false
```